# Tamanhos de divs ( Width e Height ) com posições Relativas e/ou Absolutas

Tags: css, posicionamento

Estou tendo problemas ao posicionar items (`div`'s), no caso, preciso que a primeira `div`, ocupe toda a altura e largura da tela, já as demais, ocupem apenas o `padding` que recebem e o tamanho do conteúdo de dentro dela (sem vazar conteúdo caso o mesmo seja maior, como por exemplo texto).

Como posso fazer usando `position relative`, e como posso fazer com `absolute` ?

- As `section`'s não podem se sobrepor

```css
.main-content{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding:6px 0;
}
.section{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding:6px;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="section banner"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: não entendi bem sua duvida, o conteúdo esta ultrapassando a div em que contem o conteudo ou esta ultrapassando o `main-content`?

Comment: A dúvida é como fazer, de forma que não ultrapasse, e que os outros `sections` sigam o fluxo sem se sobrepor, ta escrito ...

Comment: ultrapassar na horizontal ou na vertical? você pode colocar os dados que esta usando para ver como fica?

Comment: não ultrapassar na horizontal obviamente :D

Comment: Ta tudo ai, é apenas um exemplo pra ver como pode ser feito...

Comment: Ainda não está claro.

Comment: a div tem que ocupar 100% da altura e largura da página, e não pode sobrepor ou ser sobreposta por outras

Comment: huahuahua se ocupar 100% da pagina como não pode ser sobreposta por outras?

Comment: as outras são jogadas logo abaixo

Comment: no caso é o height da parte visivel da página, ocupando 100% dele e do width

Comment: tá muito enrolado, retirei a resposta. visite essa página Como fazer uma boa pergunta? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Faz uma imagem no photoshop ou paint ilustrando como você precisa que fique, senão fica difícil de entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra fazer com que as divs internas não vazem, tente utilizar `*{box-sizing: border-box;}` no CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-content{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding:6px 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.section{
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  padding:6px;
  width:100%;
}
.section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="section banner"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

E para manter o elemento com altura 100%, tente com jQuery

```js
$(window).bind("load resize", function() {
 // Será executado quando o documento carregar
  //ou quando o usuário redimensionar a tela (zoom)

  // Caso utilize Navbar, dar o valor de sua altura + margem
  // Exemplo: Navbar possui 30px de largura + 10px de margin-bottom
  // topOffset = 40;
 topOffset = 0;
 height = ((this.window.innerHeight > 0) ? this.window.innerHeight : this.screen.height);
  
  // \/ Altura da página - valor da Navbar (topOffset)
 height = height - topOffset;
 if (height < 1) height = 1;
 if (height > topOffset) {
  $(".wrapper").css("min-height", (height) + "px");
    // /\ Elemento alvo
 }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 8px 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  Wrapper aqui
</div>
```

Comment: mas e o height de 100% da visualização da tela ? :3

Comment: Editado ;) tenta agora